# Is there a better solution for this LCM problem?

Tags: algorithm, math

- Suppose we have been given a number N which is a positive integer `2 <= N <= 10^9`.
- We need to Find two integers `A` and `B` such that
  - `(A+B) = N, and LCM(A,B) is Minimum possible.`
- For example if `N = 9 then A = 3, B = 6` are the only valid answers.

**What i Have thought Till Now**

- If `N is even` then `A,B` will be `N/2`.
- If N is Odd then `A,B` will be such that `A is a perfect factor of B and A+B = N`.

**What i need to Know**

- `Am i doing right ?`
- `Did i miss something ?`
- `Is there any better solution for this ?`

Comment: Can u kindly provide the reference to the problem

Comment: Original problem link - https://codeforces.com/contest/1372/problem/B

Comment: Voting to close because it's a maths question - not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the A, B with the lowest LCM is the same as finding the A, B with the largest GCD. The largest possible GCD is the largest factor of N (excluding N itself).

So if K is the largest factor of N, then A=K, B=K*(N/K-1) is one solutions. All solutions are of the form A=jK, B=K(N/K-j), where 1 <= j < N/K.

You can find the largest factor of N in sqrt(N) time by finding the smallest i in [2, sqrt(N)] that divides N; the largest factor is then N/i.

For example, the largest factor of 9 (excluding 9 itself) is 3, so A=3, B=3*(3-1)=6.

Comment: When you say "finding the A, B with the lowest LCM is the same as finding the A, B with the largest GCD", aren't you neglecting the fact that the product `AB` changes over all pairs `A`, `B` with fixed sum? For example if `N = 25`, `A = 10` and `B = 15` is not a solution, since it gives a greater LCM than the case `A = 5` and `B = 20`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson yes, I think you're right. I'd delete my answer, but it's been accepted.

Comment: I think your answer is correct (that `A=K`, `B=K*(N/K-1)` is a solution), apart from the "All solutions are of the form ..." bit.

Answer (score 0):

Using Above Approach By `@Paul Hankin` finally Made a solution, Thank you very much.

C++14 solution.

```
ll n,A,B; cin >> n; // long long
        if( n % 2 == 0 ) { A = n/2 ; B = n/2 ; }
        else if(isprime(n)) { A = 1 ; B = n-1 ; }
        else
        {
            ll K;
            for(ll i = 3; i <= sqrt(n) ; i++ )
            {
                if( n % i == 0) { K = n/i ; break; }
            }
            A = K, B = n-K;
        }
```

**function for prime-check used in above program**

```
bool isprime(ll n)
{
    for( ll i = 2 ; i <= sqrt(n) ; i++ )
        if(n%i==0)return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Rather than impreciseness of floating point math of `sqrt(n)` and potentially recalculating the square root repeatedly, consider `for( ll i = 2 ; i <= n/i ; i++ )`,

Answer (score 0):

I believe in simple maths.

The hints given by you were very important.

**Case 1:**

If N is even => A = N/2, B = N/2

**Case 2:**

If N is prime => A = 1, B = N-1;

**Case 3:**

If N is odd => This is tricky.

Now, if `A + B = N`, maximum value of A possible (considering A<=B) is `N/2`.

Also, to **minimise** the LCM of A and B, the `LCM(A, B) = max(A, B) = B` .... eq(1)

A + B = N .... eq(2)

B = d*A, where d is any positive integer (from eq(1)) .... eq(3)

Substituting, eq(3) in eq(2), we get,

A + d*A = N

A(1 + d) = N

A = N/(d+1) .... eq(4)

Now, the goal is to minimise the LCM => which in turn is to minimise max(A, B) = B

If we want to minimise B, we need to maximise A (from eq(4))

To maximise A, we need to minimise (d+1).

Therefore, `(d+1) = D = smallest factor of N`, where (D) >= 3 and d = D-1.

Final Answer, A = N/(d+1) and B = d*A

Have a look at the following implementation which has **Accepted** verdict on Codeforces:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

typedef long long int LL;

bool isPrime(LL n)
{
    for(LL i = 2 ; i <= sqrt(n) ; i++ )
        if(n%i==0)return false;
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    int t;
    std::cin >> t; 

    while(t--){
        
        LL n, A, B;
        std::cin>>n;

        if( n % 2LL == 0 ) { 
            A = n/2LL ;
            B = n/2LL ; 
        }
        else if(isPrime(n)) {
            A = 1LL ;
            B = n-1LL ; 
        }
        else{
            
            LL D;
            for(LL i = 3; i <= sqrt(n) ; i++ )
            {
                if( n % i == 0) { 
                    D = i; 
                    break; 
                }
            }
            LL d = D - 1LL;
            A = n/(d+1LL);
            B = d*A;
        }

        std::cout<<A<<" "<<B<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary `LL` in `n % 2 == 0`?    Also [remove FP idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858403/is-there-a-better-solution-for-this-lcm-problem#comment111182936_62859429).